# Question regarding SF User Name, and Email updates while keeping passwords

Tags: user, passwords, reset-password

Our company is rebranding , thus we need to update both the salesforce (SF) user name and email for both the Marketing and System Admin user accounts we need for an external client's non-production orgs. We don't need to freeze the 2 current users, just change their user names and email addresses to the ones that our network admin will be changing in Outlook. Therefore, we believe that we can maintain the passwords also. Otherwise, if we can't keep our present passwords for these 2 users, there will be more work to update the various integrations that also do api calls to SF.

Question:

1. If our Network Admin changes both the Marketing and System Admin user emails in outlook (when rebranding time arrives), and no user updates have been done on our client's lower SF orgs, we should still be able log into these orgs using the old/current username and and passwords to make the new Username and email updates to the external clients SF orgs such that the new email addresses match the ones that our Network Admin has created for our 2 Outlook marketing and System Admin users, correct?
2. After the user name and email changes have been made in Salesforce, we should still be able to keep the passwords associated with the 2 users before the username and email updates correct?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

For my company's purposes we have created the newly branded email address while creating an alias to the old email so that the SF user account will still get email directed to the user's rebranded inbox whenever email notifications are sent from SFDC to the user's old email address. The process is similar to call forwarding for phones. The alias will stay up for an "unlimited amount of time".